join files/devices in linear mode together in a linux system
In order to test joining 3 files linearly on my Linux system, I do:
fallocate -l 100M file1.image
fallocate -l 150M file2.image
fallocate -l  50M file3.image

and then I run losetup:
losetup /dev/loop1 file1.image
losetup /dev/loop2 file2.image
losetup /dev/loop3 file3.image

I found this script for joining two files:
#!/bin/sh
# Join 2 devices together
size1=`blockdev --getsz $1`
size2=`blockdev --getsz $2`
echo "0 $size1 linear $1 0
$size1 $size2 linear $2 0" | dmsetup create joined

And I start it with
./join.sh /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2

it works with two devices, they are joined together into one:
lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop1                7:1    0   100M  0 loop
└─joined           253:10   0   250M  0 dm
loop2                7:2    0   150M  0 loop
└─joined           253:10   0   250M  0 dm

I then remove the "joined" device with dmsetup remove joined and adjust the script for 3 device files:
#!/bin/sh
# Join 3 devices together
size1=`blockdev --getsz $1`
size2=`blockdev --getsz $2`
size3=`blockdev --getsz $3`
echo "0 $size1 linear $1 0
$size1 $size2 linear $2 0
$size2 $size3 linear $3 0"  | dmsetup create joined

start it with
./join.sh /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3
device-mapper: reload ioctl on joined (253:10) failed: Das Argument ist ungültig
Command failed.

But it fails with the error above. What am I doing wrong?
dmesg
device-mapper: table: 253:10: linear: Gap in table (-EINVAL)
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table


at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519761/programming-a-loopback-device-consisting-of-several-files-in-linux
I found a way to use mdadm to join linearly and when I tried it, it works. I did:
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 of=a.img
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=50 of=b.img
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=150 of=c.img
losetup -f
/dev/loop0
for i in a b c; do losetup -f $i.img; done
mdadm --build /dev/md0 -l linear -n 3 /dev/loop[012]
mdadm: array /dev/md0 built and started.
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active linear loop2[2] loop1[1] loop0[0]
      307200 blocks super non-persistent 64k rounding

unused devices: <none>

lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                7:0    0   100M  0 loop
└─md0                9:0    0   300M  0 linear
loop1                7:1    0    50M  0 loop
└─md0                9:0    0   300M  0 linear
loop2                7:2    0   150M  0 loop
└─md0                9:0    0   300M  0 linear

Why does the dmsetup way not work with 3 devices?
What is the difference between the dmsetup and mdadm ways?
What is dmsetup for ...?
And is mdadm for raid?
Have i done a raid0 with 3 different disk sizes? is that possible?

It would help if you could explain which parts of the documentation of dmsetup you did understand, which parts you didn't understand, what other research you have done to understand the parts you didn't understand, and why that failed. That way, you prevent answerers wasting their time and yours by repeating stuff you already know, or repeating stuff you already read and didn't understand.

The format of linear device mapper table lines is as follows:
<target start> <mapping length> linear <source device> <source start>

Or in other words, from <source device>, starting from block position <source start> onward for <mapping length> blocks should be represented in the resulting mapping as a sequence of blocks starting from <target start>.
When joining devices together in order:

on the first line, the <target start> must be 0
on any subsequent lines, the <target start> must be equal to the sum of the sizes of all previous parts.

So, your script for three devices should be:
#!/bin/sh
# Join 3 devices together
size1=`blockdev --getsz $1`
size2=`blockdev --getsz $2`
sum12=`expr $size1 + $size2`
size3=`blockdev --getsz $3`
echo "0 $size1 linear $1 0
$size1 $size2 linear $2 0
$sum12 $size3 linear $3 0"  | dmsetup create joined

Or for an arbitrary number of devices:
#!/bin/sh
usage() {
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <target name> <component...>" >&2
    exit 64 # EX_USAGE
}
if [ "$1" = "" ] || [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "-?" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]
then
    usage
fi

if [ -e "/dev/mapper/$1" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: target $1 already exists." >&2
    exit 73 # EX_CANTCREAT
fi
MAPNAME="$1"
shift

DMMAP=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $DMMAP" EXIT

sum=0
while [ "$1" != "" ]
do
    if [ ! -e "$1" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: $1 does not exist"
        exit 66 # EX_NOINPUT
    fi
    if [ ! -b "$1" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: $1 is not a block device"
        exit 69 # EX_UNAVAILABLE
    fi 
    srcN="$1"
    sizeN=$(blockdev --getsz "$srcN")
    echo "$sum $sizeN linear $srcN 0" >>$DMMAP
    sum=$(expr $sum + $sizeN)
    shift
done
dmsetup create $MAPNAME < $DMMAP

To use this script, specify the target name first, e.g.
sh ./dm-joinlinear joined /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3


thanks! how can the script be dynamically to work with how many device it becomes at the start with?
so that it can be start with 2 or something more like 6 or 8 ?

thanks for the dynamically. in howmuch.txt is the number 13, becouse i need 13 loop devices to join to one. with dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/loop[1-$(cat howmuch.txt)] only loop1 and loop3 are joined to one. dmsetup ls --tree one (253:23) ├─ (7:3) └─ (7:1) how to fix this?

/dev/loop[1-13] expands to  only/dev/loop1 /dev/loop3, because within brackets is a range of characters from 1 to 1 (= just 1), or character 3. Use dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/loop? /dev/loop??, unless you have more active loop devices than you want to join together.

dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/loop? /dev/loop?? works, but what other ways exists they are more accurate? directly to say from start-/dev/loop to end-dev/loop is better.

"More accurate?" The shell will always supply wildcard expansions in alphanumerically sorted order. If you want from loop6 to loop42, you can do it with dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/loop[6-9] /dev/loop[1-3]? /dev/loop4[0-2]. Yes, it's a little more clumsy than just supplying the start and end numbers, but my script will be usable even if there are gaps in loop device numbering or the list needs to be out of order - you'll have to just list the devices explicitly then.

dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/loop[6-9] /dev/loop[1-3]? /dev/loop4[0-2] is a good way, thanks! but my problem is that i have file parts.txt there are the value in how many loop-devices are needed and i dont know a way to bring the value to the dm-joinlinear.sh

Perhaps you should open a new question describing exactly what your parts.txt contains, and if there is just a single number of loop devices, how to identify the device to start from. This is going way beyond what the original question was.

here goes on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/780353/dont-know-the-right-titel-at-the-moment

@user447274 I’m not at all sure that I understand what you’re asking, but you might want to look at Glob with Numerical Order.

Create executable script mapdevlist:
#!/bin/sh
mapname=$1
mapdev=/dev/mapper/$mapname
test -e "$mapdev" && {
    printf '%s already exists\n' "$mapdev"
    exit 1
}
shift
at=0
for dev do
    sz=$( blockdev --getsz "$dev" )
    printf '%u %u linear %s 0\n' \
           "$at" "$sz" "$dev"
    at=$(( $at + $sz )) # for POSIX sh
    # (( at += sz ))    # for Bash, Zsh etc
done |
dmsetup create "$mapname"

Call this like:
mapdevlist newmapdevname /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3 …

