join a specific number of files/devices in linear mode together in a linux system
For joining in Linux files/devices in linear mode together i have this script dm-joinlinear.sh from
join files/devices in linear mode together in a linux system , thanks telcoM
#!/bin/sh
usage() {
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <target name> <component...>" >&2
    exit 64 # EX_USAGE
}
if [ "$1" = "" ] || [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "-?" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]
then
    usage
fi

if [ -e "/dev/mapper/$1" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: target $1 already exists." >&2
    exit 73 # EX_CANTCREAT
fi
MAPNAME="$1"
shift

DMMAP=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $DMMAP" EXIT

sum=0
while [ "$1" != "" ]
do
    if [ ! -e "$1" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: $1 does not exist"
        exit 66 # EX_NOINPUT
    fi
    if [ ! -b "$1" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: $1 is not a block device"
        exit 69 # EX_UNAVAILABLE
    fi
    srcN="$1"
    sizeN=$(blockdev --getsz "$srcN")
    echo "$sum $sizeN linear $srcN 0" >>$DMMAP
    sum=$(expr $sum + $sizeN)
    shift
done
dmsetup create $MAPNAME < $DMMAP

i run the script with
./dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/loop? /dev/loop??

or
./dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/mapper/file? /dev/mapper/file??




/dev/loop0 and /dev/mapper/file1 are the same
/dev/loop1 and /dev/mapper/file2 are the same
....
/dev/loop32 and /dev/mapper/file33 are the same

i can run the script with
dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/loop[0-9] /dev/loop[1-2]? /dev/loop3[0-2]

or
dm-joinlinear.sh one /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 .... and so on up to /dev/loop32 (to long to write all down here all)

or the same with remove "loop" and use mapper/file , but than starting from 1 and not from 0
i prefer the way with /dev/mapper/file instead of /dev/loop
but how do i say dm-joinlinear.sh how much devices they have to join? the value is in parts.txt

You can use a for loop to iterate from zero to 32, and store the device names in an array.
# you don't show the file, there are programmatic ways to acquire this number
n=33

devices=()
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do
  devices+=("/dev/loop${i}")
done

dm-joinlinear.sh one "${devices[@]}"

